# How to get DOM element in Angular 2 with pure ES6?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get DOM Element or the data-attribute in Angular 2 without using TypeScript's ElementRef?

I'm using templating engine to render the container.. trying to get Angular to read data-attribute. Is there any ES6 / pure JS way to grab it?

Answer (score 0):

ElementRef isn't a TypeScript thing ... it is an Angular thing. So you should be able to access it using ES6 and ViewChild.

See the docs here: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

And the issue discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7906

Comment: the docs comes from element_ref.ts... looks like a typescript file to me. Also the issue discussion didn't say anything about ES6. I will try if babel-plugin-angular2-annotations works.

Comment: All of Angular is written in TypeScript ... so if you want to ensure you are not using any TypeScript files ... it seems you would not be able to use Angular at all? Here is ngIf for example: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Component works fine without TS. I could use "inputs" instead of Input.. wondering if there's a way to grab the element or data-attribute too.

Comment: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html

I tried using Component.annotation and it works fine. But the .parameters with Attribute doesn't work as expected